# Add programmatically UIImageView adapted for 3.5 and 4 inch

Tags: uiimageview, uiimage, frame

[image]

I would like to add an UIImageView to this view. Can anyone help me please?

The problem is the compatibilities for 4/3.5 inch

I tryed this

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, self.view.bounds.size.height)];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

but the image comes out of the screen!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controllers are created with a default size and resized after `viewDidLoad`. Depending on where you are creating your image view, it could cause you problems

Add this code:

```
imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Also make sure that you don't have other views that you don't want to step over with your image, like the bottom toolbar